# X-Rite Color Picker software alternative?

Tags: color-conversion

We have a very old Mac running X-Rite color picker. This software is awesome because it converts spot colors to CMYK based on our proprietary icc profile with the ability to limit the conversion to a particular number of process inks that fall within a certain delta value.

Unfortunately, this software does not run on modern Mac OS systems. I think we've had this loaded on an old Mac for the past 15 years!

What alternative software is out there that allows us to import our .cxf Pantone color libraries where we can see these conversions with the capabilities mentioned above? This can't be done In RIP. Our workflow requires we create our resulting cmyk conversion within our working Illustrator files before creating our Production PDF files that will eventually go thru our GMG proofing system.

Here is a pic of what the interface looks like.
[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Have you tried contacting X-rite to see if they have an up to date alternative to that software?  I think that would be your best bet to be honest.